# Qual a diferença entre endpoint e API?

Tags: api, terminologia

Eu sempre usei *endpoint* e *API* como sinônimos. Hoje descobri que eles não querem dizer a mesma coisa, embora estejam relacionados.

Afinal, qual a diferença entre esses dois?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Um ***endpoint*** de um *web service* é a URL onde seu serviço pode ser acessado por uma aplicação cliente.

Uma ***API*** é um conjunto de rotinas, protocolos e ferramentas para construir aplicações.

***API*s podem existir sem *endpoints***. Na [lista de APIs do windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list) você pode verificar que a grande maioria trata de conteúdo local - como exibir janelas, ou como gerenciar o *input* de teclado e mouse.

***Endpoints* também podem existir sem *API*s**. Imagine uma implementação simples, que retorna apenas a data e hora do servidor; a simplicidade da operação não exige a implementação de uma *API* exclusivamente para isso.

Hoje em dia é comum se referir a uma coleção de *endpoints* pertencentes a um dado serviço como *API*, por proximidade e acoplamento; em muitos casos o serviço é desenhado e planejado tendo em mente a exposição via *endpoints*.

Um modelo típico de implementação pode ser interpretado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde *endpoints* são interfaces entre a *API* e a aplicação consumidora.

Comment: (Pitaco) Sou digamos mais purista sobre a definição de API: se expõe uma interface pública (conjunto de rotinas que podem ser chamadas por um cliente) então é uma API, sem distinção sobre ser uma ferramenta ou protocolo. Nesse caso, me parece que um endpoint não pode existir sem uma API, pois há uma interface pública (a URL) e o cliente dessa interface (quem chama a URL).

Comment: @Piovezan Essa é uma definição interessante, e entendo seu (válido) ponto de vista. Porém esta definição de API poderia ser aplicada a qualquer objeto com propriedades públicas que é comsumido por outro; eu diria eu um nível mínimo de complexidade de processo é necessário para merecer essa definição. Uma discussão a respeito do que define uma API, framework ou plataforma pode ser uma questão com respostas bem interessantes

Comment: Verdade. Particularmente me dei por satisfeito com [essa definição](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-a-platform-and-a-technology) de plataformas e frameworks, acrescida à ideia de que um framework é um recurso opcional; ele facilita a implementação de uma aplicação, embora impondo uma forma de fazer, mas daria para fazer a aplicação sem ele, embora com mais trabalho.

Answer (score 14):

Endpoint e API não possuem absolutamente nada em comum.

Endpoint, além do sentido genérico de "algo que está nas pontas", é mais usado hoje em comunicação de dados, e se refere a duas "pontas" que estão se comunicando através de algum protocolo de comunicação de dados.

Mais especificamente, endpoint também se refere às duas "pontas" de uma conexão TCP (como um browser no lado cliente e um web server no lado servidor). Neste caso, endpoint é um termo técnico e se refere ao par (endereço IP, porta TCP) de cada ponta da conexão TCP.

É possível ver os endpoints TCP através do comando "netstat" no terminal.
Por exemplo:

```
xx@xx~]$ netstat -an -t  
...
...  
tcp    0  0 192.168.0.24:34904  198.252.206.25:80   ESTABELECIDA
...
...
```

está mostrando uma conexão TCP onde o endpoint local é **192.168.0.24:34904** e o endpoint remoto é **198.252.206.25:80**. O endereço IP 198.252.206.25 pertence a um site da rede StackExchange, e 80 é a porta HTTP. Consequentemente o endpoint local 192.168.0.24:34904 está sendo utilizado pelo Firefox em meu computador, nesta comunicação com o StackOverflow.

Uma API é basicamente um conjunto de declaração de funções, classes, estruturas, protocolos e convenções que são necessários para se consumir os serviços de software fornecidos por algum provedor. Na prática, uma API é quase sempre um conjunto de funções e seus parâmetros, em alguma linguagem de programação como C, Java, JavaScript, etc.

Por exemplo, para se escrever aplicações para o sistema operacional Windows utiliza-se a API do Windows, mais conhecida como API WIN32. Para se desenvolver aplicações para Android utiliza-se a API do Android, que é basicamente a API fornecida pela linguagem Java mais APIs adicionais específicas do sistema Android. Para se desenvolver aplicações web utilizam-se APIs específicas em JavaScript, web services, REST, etc, como as fornecidas por Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Answer (score -3):

Um endpoint é a localização de onde APIs podem acessar um recurso. 
Um endpoint de um web service é a URL + URN = URI.

Comment: Olá user. Perante as outras respostas do post sua resposta soa um pouco desprovida de detalhes. Tente adicionar informações que complementem a discussão de forma sadia especialmente em perguntas que ja foram feitas a algum tempo.