# O que significa o termo "Consumir uma API"?

Tags: api, terminologia

Muito vejo esse termo por aqui, qual seria seu significado, e de que forma se obtém isso através de código?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre endpoint e API?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86399/18246)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A palavra consumir é sinônimo de utilizar e gastar.

No contexto de programação seria utilizar ao menos uma das funcionalidades que a API proporciona, você estaria assim consumindo-a.

Answer (score 16):

Significa usá-la :) Significa que seu código vai acessá-la de alguma forma. Invocará as ações disponíveis para requisitar informações, mandar realizar operações. Basta escrever um código que faça uma requisição nela, já está consumindo-a. Não importa o tipo de API.

Reforço que consome-se a API, ela sequer precisa fornecer dados.

Hoje muita gente acha que API é algo para web, o que não é, só isso.

Pense em uma *string*, você precisa pegar um trecho dela, chama o método `substr()`, pronto já está consumindo a API de *string*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md

Answer (score -2):

Consumir é utilizar os recursos de quem esta provendo a API. A API é um sistema intermediário que facilita a troca de informações entre os sistemas.