# Como retornar um json para o mesmo template com django?

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando retornar um json para o mesmo template sem renderizá-lo de novo (como no caso do render(request, 'dir/base.html', response))) utilizando o JsonResponse, mas está dando esse erro: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable. Não entendo, porque estou passando uma variável no formato json. Existe outro método?

```
response = {
        'classified': classified,
        'label': label
    }

return JsonResponse(request, response)
```

No HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'documents:classify' %}" name="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Classify</button>

</form>
{% if classified %}
    <br>
    Classification: <strong> {{ label }}</strong>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de uma troca de informações nos comentários/chat, entendi o objetivo, o que vc quer, essencialmente, é executar algo no back-end retornar para o front-end sem a re-renderização da template django. Resolvi reformular a resposta, mas antes vamos discorrer sobre alguns conceitos abordados na conversa:

**Endpoint:**
Endpoint é, em sintese, o endereço de um serviço exposto, ou ainda "o que o serviço expõe", as tês principais característica de um endpoint são expressas na sigla ABC (Address, Binding e Contract), podemos fazer uma associação análoga a essas características da seguinte forma: Address é onde o serviço está hospedado, Binding é como o serviço pode ser acessado, e Contract seria o que pode ser obtido com o serviço. As [respostas essa pergunta, aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86399/7412), complementam essa explanação.

Porque a elucidação do Endpoint? Para deixar claro para voce que o endpoint é um serviço do lado back-end, ou seja mesmo que voce desenvolva um endpoint, e para isso eu  recomendaria estudar o [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), se gosta de "mão na massa" começe logo pelo [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/), ainda assim não resolveria o problema da forma que voce quer fazer, vou tentar deixar mais claro com alguns exemplos baseado no seu codigo, mas não sem antes explicar o conceito crucial para trabalhar com templates django:

**Contexto:**
Em função da otmização, as templates no django são compiladas **somente uma vez** e armazenadas para usos posteriores. Uma template pode ter nomes de variáves dentro de duplas chaves, como por exemplo: `{{ nome }}` e `{{ sobrenome }}`.
Um contexto é um dicionário no qual as chaves são os nomes das variáveis e os valores representam seus valores (nada mais óbvio). Quando passamos este contexto para o método de renderização `{{ nome }}` pode ser "resolvida" como `foo` e `{{ sobrenome }}` como `bar`, claro que é só um exemplo simplório. O objeto `context` representa o contexto no qual a template foi renderizada. Voce pode ver maiores detalhes [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/templates/api/) e [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/templates/language/)

Vamos a um exemplo (simplório, novamente, :-)) no qual a template solicita ao usuario uma data e um valor numérico, os dados são passados para a view e, após, o primeiro `submit`, é aplicado um cálculo no valor numérico (multplicado por 2) e devolvido para a template, segue o código:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="data">Data:</label>
    <input id="data" type="date" name="data" value="" /><br>
    <label for="valor">Valor:</label>
    <input id="valor" type="number" name="valor" value="" /><br>
    <input type="submit">
    {% if data != None %}
        <br><br>
        <p>
            Sua última digitação:<br>
            Data Inicial: {{data}}<br>
            Valor: {{valor}}<br>
            Valor Corrigido: {{new_valor}}<br>
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Agora vamos desenvolver uma view baseado no fragmento da view que vce colocou na pergunta

```
def my_view(request):
    contexto = {'data': None, 'valor': None, 'new_valor': None}
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.POST['data']
        valor = request.POST['valor']
        new_valor = int(valor)*2
        contexto = JsonResponse({'data': data, 'valor': valor, 'new_valor': new_valor})
        return contexto

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', contexto)
```

**Porque não funciona?**
Tente isso em casa e vc não vai ter o mesmo erro que vc relata na pergunta, mas não vai funcionar da forma que vc espera, porque? por que a não ser que vc utilize [mixins com as CBVs (Class-Based-Views)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) (**O que não chega a ser trivial**), voce sempre terá que re-renderizar a view (pelo menos da forma que vc esta utilizando as templates/views). Nesse meu exemplo vc verá que embora não seja levantada uma exceção, a sua template será substituida por um parse do json enviado (depende da versão do browser), [no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/json-test-1) ocorrerá o erro no browser `CSRF verification failed`. Se fosse enviado esse contexto para a template seria gerado um erro, pois o objeto não é um tipo dicionário, contexto tem que, necessariamente, ser do tipo `dict`.

Agora vamos analisar o seu trecho de código:

```
response = {
        'classified': classified,
        'label': label
    }

return JsonResponse(request, response)
```

O que vc está tentando fazer na última linha: Passando para `JsonResponse` dois objetos, um do tipo `request` e outro do tipo `dict`, esperando algum retorno e, finalmente, tentando retornar para o "browser", mas se vc fizer em um terminal python: `help(JsonResponse)` voce verá que o primeiro parametro a ser enviado para essa classe tem que ser um serializavel, e como *default* um tipo dicionário. Voce está enviando um request.

Abra um terminal django e faça o seguinte teste:

```
>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = {
    'classified': 1,
    'label': 'label'
    }

>>> data_json1 = JsonResponse(response)    
>>> print(data_json1)
<JsonResponse status_code=200, "application/json">

>>> print(data_json1.content)
b'{"classified": 1, "label": "label"}'
```

**Re-renderizando:**
Voce pode re-renderizar o contexto da seguinte forma na view (veja essa versão no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/json-test-2)):

```
def home(request):
    contexto = {'data': None, 'valor': None, 'new_valor': None}
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.POST['data']
        valor = request.POST['valor']
        new_valor = int(valor)*2
        contexto = {'data': data, 'valor': valor, 'new_valor': new_valor}
        return render(request, 'main/index.html', contexto)

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', contexto)
```

Ai voce pode questionar, mas dessa forma eu teria que "reconstruir" todo o contexto para alterar apenas uma variável? Pelo menos até onde eu saiba, para o tipo "Old" de views que vc está usando, a resposta é sim, quer mudar isso? Novamente: Estude as [CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/).

**Então é impossível acessar algo no back-end sem a re-renderização?**
A resposta é não, há vários caminhos, mas nenhum deles tão simples que daria para elucidar nessa resposta, como já mencionado anteriormente, utilizando [mixins com as CBVs (Class-Based-Views)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) voce pode conseguir resultados impensáveis com views no velho estilo, que vc está usando.

Talvez o caminho mais óbvio é desenvolver uma **REST API** ([veja as respostas a essa pergunta, aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/7412)), na qual o django seria essencialmente o back-end fornecendo os **endpoints** (novamente, sugeriria o [DRF](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=django%20rest%20framework&oq=django%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l4j69i57.1743j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), e o front-end poderia seria desenvolvido em um FW específico para front-end, como por exemplo [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/),  [React.Js](https://reactjs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), etc.

**Então a melhor forma é sempre re-renderizar para continuar usando django templates?**
Sim e não, para continuar usando as django templates sem ter que ficar re-renderizando, voce precisa executar os requests de forma assincrona para continuar na mesma página, para isso vc vai ter que usar o AJAX no lado front-end, e, embora, na minha opinião, essa seja a melhor escolha (se for um desenvolvedor solo, ou não tem equipes separadas para back e front), está longe de ser trivial. Voce pode começar com esse guia: [Django e AJAX Form - Diga 'adeus' ao refresh de pagina](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)

**Bonus: The messages framework:**
Sem conhecer o seu contexto, arrisco dizer que o [framework messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) pode ser útil para voce, se não para esse caso específico, com certeza para muitos outros, veja o texto da sua apresentação:

"Muito comum em aplicativos web, muitas vezes é necessário exibir uma mensagem de notificação de forma "estanque" (também chamada de "mensagens flash") após o processamento de entradas do usuário.

Para isso, o Django fornece suporte completo para mensagens baseadas em cookies e em sessões, tanto para usuários anônimos quanto para usuários autenticados. A estrutura de mensagens permite armazenar temporariamente as mensagens em um `request` e recuperá-las para exibição em um `request subsequente` (geralmente o próximo). Cada mensagem é marcada com um nível específico que determina sua prioridade (por exemplo, informações, aviso ou erro)."

**Conclusão:**
Eu sempre digo que eu amo o Django, mas se tivesse que apontar algo que incomoda seria o nível de abstração, por isso é muito dificil aprender esse framework "na cabeçada", até para postar e entender uma pergunta/resposta em um site como esse é complicado, mas de uma coisa é preciso estar ciente: Se vc quer aproveitar realmente os recursos da linguagem, saia das views no velho estilo e, principalmente, leia a documentação.

Veja a [versão 1](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/json-test-1) e [versão 2](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/json-test-2) dos exemplos no repl.it:

Comment: Entendi, @Sidon. Mas como eu faria para retornar esse json sem renderizar o template? Bastaria dar return diretamente ou usaria alguma classe Response?

Comment: Basta fazer a mudança que eu indiquei, só coloque as aspas e retorne.

Comment: Houve esse erro aqui: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'.

Comment: Vc tem que converter para json na template. Estou no celular, assim q ir p computer vejo p vc

Comment: Como vc esta tratando o response na template? poste o codigo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para adicionar o código do template.

Comment: Estou impossibilitado de rodar django localmente e, infelizmente, no repl.it ainda esta muito limitado, mas só pelo seu codigo não da para entender qual a necessidade de enviar um json, apenas o contexto não seria suficiente, com json vc vai ter que fazer o parse com JS na template.

Comment: Essa parte de context ainda não estudei. Você poderia me fornecer um exemplo de como seria?

Comment: To meio atolado aqui, mas me explica o que vc precisa fazer que tento ajudar, vamos mover para o chat, ok?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92265/discussion-between-sidon-and-antonio-braz-finizola).

Comment: Resposta editada, de acordo com o que foi exeplicado no chat.

Comment: Obrigado, @Sidon. Irei ler com calma porque foram muitas explicações.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro é

```
Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable
```

Isso significa que o módulo json está funcionando, ele está tentando converter alguma coisa pra json, e não sabe como. Essa "coisa" é um objeto do tipo `ndarray`.

Como seu objeto é esse:

```
response = {
        'classified': classified,
        'label': label
    }
```

Isso significa que ou `classified` ou `label` **é** ou **contém** objetos do tipo `ndarray` dentro.

O módulo json precisa trabalhar com os tipos primitivos do python: `str`, `float`, `int`, `bool`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict` e `set`. Outros objetos não podem ser convertidos para json automaticamente, você tem que converter para uma combinação desses objetos acima antes de passar para o `JsonResponse`.

`ndarray` não faz parte do python, vem de alguma biblioteca externa. Uma biblioteca popular que tem uma classe chamada `ndarray` é a `numpy`. O módulo json não sabe lidar com `ndarray`. Se você tem uma `numpy.ndarray()` deve chamar o método `tolist()` para convertê-la para lista, antes de tentar serializar em json:

```
minha_lista = minha_ndarray.tolist()
```