# Como acessar um endpoint POST de uma view do django?

Tags: django, python-requests

Preciso disponibilizar um serviço que faz uma requisição a um método de uma view do django usando a lib **requests**. O método é o seguinte:

```
def classify(request):                                    

    print(request)

    if request.method == "POST":                          
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  

        if form.is_valid():                               
            clf = Classifying()                           
            file = request.FILES['file']                  
            file_name = str(file.name)                    
            predict = str(clf.predict(file))                                      

            response = {                                      
                'predict': predict,                           
                'document': file_name,                        
                'run': True                                   
            }                                                 

         data = json.dumps(response, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
         return HttpResponse(data)                         

return HttpResponse({})
```

No momento, o método captura um arquivo do request, mas isso será modificado depois. O objetivo desse método é pegar um texto, classificar e retornar a classificação (1 ou 0, nesse caso). Fiz um form simples com html para testar esse método e o mesmo funciona. Mas quando utilizei a lib **requests** não funcionou. Esse método nem mesmo é chamado (coloquei o print acima para verificar se pelo menos imprimia o conteúdo do request). Código:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/classify', data={'text': 'Excelentissimo Juíz...'})
print(r.url)
```

A resposta do print é **Response [500]**. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Se o código da resposta é 500, basta abrir o log de erros do servidor que você está usando e ver qual é o erro.

Comment: E onde esta o codigo que voce desenvolveu para o `endpoint` o que vc utilzou para isso?

Comment: Pelo visto vc esta fazendo confusão com o conceito de `endpoint`, reformulei [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374719/7412), leia-a inteira que, provavelmente, vc ter a resposta para essa nova pergunta tb.